# How to take a control of specific cell of XL?

Tags: excel, qtp, hp-uft

Below is my code to open XL file.

```
Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")

myxl.Workbooks.Open "E:\Employment.xls" 

myxl.Application.Visible = true
```

Here I am facing 1 issue. This code is able to open the XL file but it get displayed at task bar only. I am not able see the contents of xl file. refer attached screen shot for more details

2] My second issue is 
I want take a screenshot of 300th row and 8th column cell. I am able to read the data of this specific cell through UFT but cant scroll to this cell so that i can take screenshot of cell(300,8)

Comment: refer to what screenshot?  You've not added one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can open the excel in maximized mode as below:

   myxl.WindowState = -4137
2. To scroll to cell (300,8), you can use the following:

   myxl.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 300

   myxl.ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8

Let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

As Gman said, force the window to maximised state:

```
myxl.WindowState = -4137
```

Then simply select the cell you want to take the screenshot of:

```
myxl.Cells(300,8).select
```

Note that this will select row 300, column 8 in the active workbook and the active worksheet, so ensure you have selected the correct worksheet before this step, or specify it within the `.Select` step directly.

You can then take the screenshot with UFT's standard `Desktop.CaptureBitmap <filepath and name to save>` command

Comment: Hi Gman and Dave, 
  Your solution for scroll down to specific cell worked for me. Thanks....

Gman,
As I said, XL get displayed at taskbar but it doesn't get open. Your solution 'myxl.WindowState = -4137' is not working. 
Currently I have used 'Insight recoding ' to open XL but I am not happy with Insight recording solution. 

Is there any other way to open XL file?

Comment: You can use the 'Run' method of an object of type "Wscript.Shell". In UFT, we have SystemUtil.Run, which you can make use of. In both these methods, you can pass the parameters to maximize/minimize/restore the window state. Refer this link for help on Run method: https://ss64.com/vb/run.html